# Was there any Rishi/Sant/Saint by the name of Maadan?

Tags: history, identification-request, rishi

I was reading an article about Shukracharya [here](https://allahisshukracharya.webs.com/allah-and-shukracharya), which says:

> There lived Saint Maadan in ancient India, once he visits an
>   Ashram (residential area for saints in jungle) and see beautiful
>   daughter of a saint. Maadan got exited and his sperms(Shukra-Anu) come
>   out and stained his langot(underwear). He immediately throw away his
>   underwear and get another one. After few days she turns to m.c. and uses
>   langot thrown away by Maadan as pad. As a result she
>   gets pregnant. Finding this,his father throw her out of Ashram and call
>   her unborn child Adham(mean) or Neech(hindi) and cursed that he will
>   give birth to Mlecchha. Here Maadan roaming here and there came upon to
>   girl and sees that there was no fault of her and she accidentally got
>   pregnant. Frowning on people who have teased her,he gives many offering
>   to unborn child and says that my son will go to west(Arab
>   countries) and invent a new religion which will do opposite of these
>   eastern people who have tormented the innocent girl. Madina is named
>   after Saint Maadan. Here Adham marries demon girl Havva(Eve)and give
>   birth to Mlecchha people(Aadmi). Near Arab countries there are 3
>   countries Mali,Somalia,Malawi named after maternal grandfathers of
>   demon king Raavan i.e.Mali,Sumali& Malyawan which confirms that there
>   once lived demons.

My questions:

1. Who is this saint being referred here (provided the story is true)?
2. If the story is true then are there any references to this in our scriptures?
3. If the story is false do let me know and I'll delete the question.

Comment: This story is false!! The article itself seems to be very very very wrong!

Comment: This story is false. No scripture mention it.